# is it possible to access a DataDog trace_id from within a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datadog

We are using DataDog's Distributed tracing in a rails application and would like to write the trace_id (for a controller#action) so that we could access the url later to our Rails logs. How could I do this?

something like?:

```
trace_id = DataDog.trace_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datadog's Ruby library keeps this info on the struct `Datadog.tracer.active_correlation`.

You can call `Datadog.tracer.active_correlation.trace_id` to grab the trace ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think with ddtrace 1.0, this becomes

```
Datadog::Tracing.correlation.trace_id
```